# Desktop App Converter "Fatal Error 1000"

Tags: win-universal-app, converters, windows-10-desktop

I receive the following error when attempting to run the Desktop App Converter (Project Centennial):

```
Assert-RequiredFeatureEnabled: fatal error 1000: required feature is not installed or enabled. Please refer to machine setup instructions.
At C:\Users\%%%\Documents\DesktopAppConverter\converter_util\EnvironmentAssertions.ps1:40 char:9
+         throw "Assert-RequiredFeatureEnabled: fatal error 1000: requi ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Assert-Required...p instructions.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Assert-RequiredFeatureEnabled: fatal error 1000: required feature is not installed or enabled. Please refer to
    machine setup instructions.
```

The relevant script is in EnvironmentAssertions.ps1:

```
$feature = Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Containers"

if (!$feature) {
    throw "Assert-RequiredFeatureEnabled: fatal error 1000: required feature is not installed or enabled. Please refer to machine setup instructions."
}
```

I found no items in Windows Features that appear related to containers.

How can this error be resolved?

*Windows 10 Pro insider preview (build 14316) and Desktop App Converter preview (0.1.8.release_2016-04-05_17-47_5aa8cc)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking around, it appears that the "Containers" feature is only on Enterprise versions of Windows 10 at the moment - perhaps they will extend this to Pro eventually, but I think that's why we can't get it working.

Comment: It appears that this is a bug, according to comments in a relevant [UserVoice issue](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/13352826-centennial-should-not-require-enterprise-edition).  The bug exists in the current flight of Pro and should be fixed in the next update.